# Reference request to introduce rigorous math to an elementary schooler

Tags: education

I would appreciate any suggestions for materials to introduce a particularly capable 2nd grader to math beyond the standard grade-level arithmetic.

Unfortunately, there is no Math Circle near-by.

I am aware of Khan Academy and their excellent material, yet I can't seem to find the ideal course there.

Thanks

Comment: What branch of math?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The topic is secondary. It's really to introduce thinking in terms beyond the typical calculator type math that is taught in our lower grade system. Maybe geometry might be good?

Comment: Geometry is definitely good (and just visual things in general, google "visual proofs"), however many (if not all) of the things being proved involve algebra.. However, modular arithmetic might be a good idea, I've heard other math educators successfully apply this topic when teaching kids.